# cowplot: axis title forcefully aligned when aligning two plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

This code replicates the problem:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(ID = letters[1:10],
                 Var = rnorm(10),
                 "Some_very_long_label_names" = rnorm(10),
                 "Not_so_long" = rnorm(10),
                 "Short" = rnorm(10),
                 "Incredibly_long_label_name_why_oh_why" = rnorm(10),
                 "Etc" = rnorm(10))
melted_df <- reshape2::melt(df)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(ID, Var)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(melted_df, aes(ID, variable)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
    guides(fill = FALSE)

cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 2, align = "v", axis = "n")
```

If you run that code, it'll yield this plot:

[image: Problematic plot]

The problem with this plot lies in the positioning of the y-axis title of the first plot. I thought perhaps setting `axis = "n"` would stop it from aligning to the axis from the second plot, but it didn't.

My desired output would be this plot, which has aligned the graphics but not the axis labels.

[image: Desired output]

Comment: `cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 2, align = "v", axis = "lr")`?

Comment: That didn't fix it here, the y-axis title didn't change position.

Comment: Now I understand what you meant, just use the `egg` package then

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the egg package. `ggarrange` worked perfectly. :) If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: already did. you just need to refresh this page :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `egg` package instead

```r
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(ID, Var)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(melted_df, aes(ID, variable)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(fill = FALSE)

library(egg)
#> Loading required package: gridExtra
ggarrange(p1, p2, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>